# Call a script function from another function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two functions created in the same script and I would like the secondary to activate the main function if cell "N1" on the "Main Stage" page were written "Ok".

```
function CallFunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Main Stage');
  var rg=sh.getRange("N1");
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  if (vA[0][0]=="Ok"){

  spreadsheet.getRange('Activate!A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=MainFunction()');
}
```

At the moment when trying to activate, it appears in the spreadsheet → You do not have the permission required to setValue (Line 10). From what I saw, I cannot activate my function directly from a spreadsheet cell.

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: If the error occurs when `=MainFunction()` is put to a cell, unfortunately, the custom function cannot use `setValue()`. It is required to use other method and/or workaround. So can you provide `=MainFunction()`?

Comment: @Tanaike Is there any way to activate the Function MainFunction() directly on script instead of typing it through the spreadsheet?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about `active` of your replying, when you want to run the function of `MainFunction()`, for example, how about modifying `spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=MainFunction()');` to `MainFunction()`?

Comment: @Tanaike I can't believe it was that simple. Thank you, I had not really stopped to imagine that simply writing the function could be activated. I thank you so much, I'm sorry I took your time for something so simple. I hope I didn't disturb you.

Comment: @Tanaike I can't mark your comment as the comment that solved the problem. I'd like to mark you as the case solver but it's not working. I only had to mark that your comment was helpful.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I posted it as an answer, because your issue and solution might be also useful other users. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to run the function of `MainFunction()` in the function of `CallFunction()`, please modify as follows. By this, `MainFunction()` can be run.

#### From:

```
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=MainFunction()');
```

#### To:

```
MainFunction();
```

#### Note:

- When `=MainFunction()` is used, unfortunately, `setValue()` cannot be used for the custom function.